# Using db4o with multiple application instances under medium trust

Tags: .net, shared-hosting, db4o, medium-trust, multiple-instances

I recently stumbled over the object database engine **[db4o](http://www.db4o.com/about/productinformation/db4o/)** which I think looks really interesting. I would like to use it in an ASP.NET MVC application that will be deployed to a shared hosting environment under **medium trust**. Because of the trust level, I'm restricted to using db4o in embedded/in-process mode.

That in itself [should be no problem](http://just3ws.wordpress.com/2009/03/11/db4o-on-shared-hosting-love/), but the hosting provider also transparently runs each web application in **multiple (load-balanced) server instances with shared storage**, which I would say is normally a very nice feature for a $10/month hoster. However, since an instance of a db4o server with write access (whether in-process or networked) **locks the underlying database file**, having multiple instances of the application using the same file won't work (or at least I can't see how it would).

**So the question is:** is it possible to use db4o in this specific environment?

I have considered letting each application have its own database which is synchronized with a master database using replication (dRS), but that approach will most likely end up with very frequent bi-directional replication (read master changes at beginning of each request, write to master after each change) which I don't think will be very efficient.

Summary of the web application/environment characteristics:

- Read-intensive (but not entirely read-only)
- Some delay (a few seconds) is acceptible between the time that a change is made and the time when the change shows up in all the application instances' data
- Must run in medium trust
- No guarantee that the load-balancer uses "sticky sessions"

All suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: you could try to ask this on the db4o forum: http://developer.db4o.com/Forums.aspx

Comment: Posted on the db4o forum: http://developer.db4o.com/Forums/tabid/98/aff/4/aft/9812/afv/topic/Default.aspx